# Is "I got a headache" correct?

Tags: tense, past-simple

> I got a headache.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

**Headache** is a countable noun. Therefore **a headache** part is correct.

Can we use simple past tense without any words like yesterday, last week etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks context. I will assume that someone called your sentence ungrammatical without saying why.

Countability is not the problem.

You may usually use the simple past tense without a time marker if the context makes the time clear. The guidelines for that are unrelated to headaches.

I suspect the problem is this:

Many native speakers use the word **got** when they mean **have**. For example,

> Father: What are you holding, son?
> Son: I **got** some cheese!

Similarly, I can imagine this conversation:

> Doctor: Where does it hurt?
> Patient: I **got** a headache.

Both of these usages of **got** are incorrect but common in speech. Both should be replaced by **have** in all but the most casual speech.

**Got** is correctly used when the intended meaning is **acquired**:

> Father: What did you buy at the supermarket?
> Son: I **got** some cheese!

This is perfectly acceptable.

If your sentence occurs in a context where a reader understands **got** to mean **have** instead of **acquired**, your reader might consider the usage an error. The absence of a time marker might cause such a misinterpretation.